# Thyristor holding current Vs VD (turn off voltage)

Tags: thyristor

I am working on a LC discharge which use a thyristor when the C capacitor voltage exeed a reference voltage. The capacitor is charged by a flyback converter. The flyback converter is stopped during the discharge and restart after the discharge done.

When I use the thyristor: **IXYS CS60-16io1** it works well. When I use another thyristor : **WEEN semiconductors TYN80W-1600T**, the discharge arrive only once time (the first discharge) and the thyristor stay ON state.

I suspect the I hold current. The I hold is 200mA at VD=6V (for **IXYS CS60-16io1**) and 200mA at 12V (for **WEEN semiconductors TYN80W-1600T**):

[image]
[image]

**Question:**

Do you know what is the I hold VS VD curve?

I notice in the datasheet the I hold decrease versus the temperature.

I suppose that the I hold is not the same versus the voltage VD.

Comment: Circuit? Waveforms? "LC discharge" implies it should reverse polarity after half a cycle, so that holding current is irrelevant; but this wouldn't be easy to arrange with a flyback wired to it.

Comment: @TimWilliams, you are right, the positive part of the discharge is done by the thyristor and the negative part by a diode. The frequency of the discharge is arround 500kHz and arrive each 55Hz (charge of the capacitor by the flyback).

Answer (score 1):

I've designed a couple of capacitor charging power supplies and, in my experience, when you turn the flyback converter off, there may be sufficient energy remaining in the flyback circuit to keep current flowing into the Thyristor and prevent it from shutting off when you expect it to. That residual energy flow comes from flyback inductance and, can keep flowing (at a low level) for much longer than you might think.

Admittedly the cap-chargers I have designed are pretty big (circa 9,000 amps pulse discharge with very specialist capacitors) but, I had a similar problem when I was simulating one of them and, had to find an alternative method of diverting thyristor current when it was dwindling down to a couple of amps (holding current level) so, maybe look into that area. I used a high-voltage MOSFET to divert holding current from the thyristor to properly and rapidly turn it off (commutation).

Comment: Thank you for the detail. I will continue to investigate. You are right, using a MOSFET High voltage should divert the holding current from the thyristor.

Answer (score 0):

More likely than the precise details of the test conditions it's because (in both cases) you are comparing a *maximum* of 200mA with a *maximum* of 200mA. There is no indication of typical or minimum values, so one could be 100mA and the other 150mA and both would easily meet the specifications.

You might notice that the specification for latching current on the IXYS part is \$\le\$ 450mA whereas it is given as \$\le\$300mA  for the WeEn part.

Perhaps you can make the WeEn part work by adding a relatively low resistor value from gate to cathode. Whatever your solution is, you should definitely test that it works at temperature extremes. At high junction temperatures such as 100°C, for example, the holding and latching currents may approximately halve.

Comment: Effectively, the latching current is not the same. Latching current is for the switch ON and not the switch OFF.

I will try to increase the junction temperature and adding a low resistor value form the gate to cathode.